# Why is communication lost in lifts?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, metals

Why is communication lost in lifts and cellars? For example, If I want to phone to someone, there is no signal communication in lift. Who may explain it?

Answer (score 7):

Most of the mobile towers have no network coverage there in underground chambers, tunnels and cellars. On the other hand, in the lift, the tower fails to catch the link as the lift acts more or less like a "*Faraday cage*" or even if it does catch the link, the phone conversation gets severely disrupted.

Quoting from the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage) link by pela in the comment below,

> Elevators and other rooms with metallic conducting frames and walls simulate a Faraday cage effect, leading to a loss of signal and "dead zones" for users of cellular phones, radios, and other electronic devices that require external electromagnetic signals. During training firemen and other first responders are cautioned that their two-way radios will probably not work inside elevator cars and to make allowances for that. Small, physical Faraday cages are used by electronics engineers during equipment testing to simulate such an environment to make sure that the device gracefully handles these conditions.

**EDIT**:In addition to what I have written about the communication failure in cellars, I am including the following:

Connections are simply electromagnetic radio waves and you won't get reception where it's impossible for a wave to pass by to. So, in basements, most waves get reflected and absorbed at many levels and also a bit attenuated, thus you can't get a proper reception over there.

Also it can be noted that whether signals can penetrate into tunnels,cellars, etc. is a function of how well they can diffract compared to the size of the corresponding structures.

From this [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_phone_signal) page on mobile signals, it can be quoted that:

> Underground areas, such as tunnels and subway stations, will lack reception unless they are wired for cell signals.

which resonates with the first line of my answer.

Comment: The signal doesn't care if the phone is moving. It's more likely because you're in a [Faraday cage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage).

Comment: @pela Thanks for correcting me.. I have included your suggestion in my answer.

Comment: I'll switch my -1 then :)

Comment: what about cellars? or underground floors?

Comment: @ITEngineer Please refer to my updated answer. The first line almost seems apt for your answer. Yet I have followed it up with whatever extra detail I could add.

Comment: Whether signals can penetrate into tunnels etc. is also a function of how well they can diffract compared to the size of the structures in question.

Comment: @RobJeffries Yours is a valid point. However as of present, the diffracting power of signals compared to the size of the tunnel is very weak and hence negligible , keeping in mind the present scenario in various places, specially the case of the London underground tube rail tunnels. Still I am including your point in my answer as it has justifiable scientific significance.